# Is a baby born in July eligible for the child tax credit?

Tags: united-states, income-tax

I do see it says the child has to live with you for more than half the year, so I assume the answer to this question is most likely no.

However, I also see this link on the IRS website which seems to indicate it might be possible: [https://www.irs.gov/faqs/filing-requirements-status-dependents/dependents/dependents-8#:~:text=Yes%2C%20if%20your%20child%20was,additional%20child%20tax%20credit%20(ACTC)](https://www.irs.gov/faqs/filing-requirements-status-dependents/dependents/dependents-8#:%7E:text=Yes%2C%20if%20your%20child%20was,additional%20child%20tax%20credit%20(ACTC)).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is "yes".

See [Publication 501](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p501#en_US_2021_publink1000220900), to which the IRS site you linked to refers:

> A child who was born or died during the year is treated as having lived with you more than half the year if your home was the child's home more than half the time he or she was alive during the year.

Comment: This is correct, when a child is born it doesn't matter what time of year how long they lived with you. My daughter was born in December of 2021 and she qualified.

Comment: @Nosjack Did you get the full credit or is it prorated? If it's full credit, it seems like additional incentive for "celebrating" Valentine's Day.

Comment: @Barmar You lose it on the other side...you don't get it for the year your child turns 18 even if they turn 18 in December. I guess on average you slightly come out ahead since some kids do die before turning 18, but probably you shouldn't do your tax planning around that.

Comment: @Barmar It is a full credit for the year, even if the kid is born on December 31st.

Comment: @user3067860 much better to have the money upfront. At the rate we're going,  by the time my child is 18 I imagine we're gonna be paid in pesos.